# How to change the colour of selected button when clicked using target method?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner and want to know how do I change the colour of the selected clicked button using the target method?

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn").length;

for (var i = 0; i < buttons; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".btn")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelectorAll(".btn").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `event` argument that you get from the click callback and the clicked element is the `.target`.

You can do:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".btn")[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  });
```

But you can do instead:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

buttons.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
event.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is currently very inefficient.

Inside the `for` loop, you are reselecting every button. You should instead select them once outside the loop.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
buttons[i].addEventListener("click", (e) =>{
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
<button class="btn">abc</button>
```

Comment: How is it different than the other answers?

Comment: The anonymous function